# JavaScript data structures , ArrayList(Java) in JS

Tags: java, javascript, node.js

I am developing a game using Java , now I am working on multiplayer mod . The server side program is written in node.js and the client side is in java . My question is about JavaScript data structures . In Java I cant do something like this

```
ArrayList<Room> rooms = new ArrayList<Room>();
```

And here is the Room which contains some data in it .

```
public class Room(){
    //Here is data about the room (clients number,clients names etc.)
}
```

I need a data strucure like **ArrayList** in JavaScript.

Comment: Java is not JavaScript, which it seems you know, but you're still mixing them in strange ways in the question, and telling us what you can't do in Java etc ?

Comment: no , I need a data structure in JS like ArrayList in Java

Comment: Can you give me a simple example how can I create a class Room and create a dynamic array of multiple Room objects ?

Comment: You can't, javascript is not Java, there are functions, objects and arrays, you can't expect to create a data structure from another language, you have to create something that is available, whatever that is.

Comment: I know that JS is not Java , I need sth equivalent to that data structure

Comment: A plain JS array of objects will give you pretty much the same functionality as a Java ArrayList.

Comment: OK , thank you the comments and the answer helped me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Javascript an array can be dynamically sized (without an `ArrayList`). For example, the documentation for [`push()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp) reads (in part)

> The `push()` method adds new items to the end of an array, and returns the new length.

You might use it like

```js
var arr = new Array();
arr.push(1);
document.getElementById("out").innerHTML += arr + "<br>";
arr.push(2);
document.getElementById("out").innerHTML += arr;
```

```html
<div id="out">
</div>
```